# Autodesk Forge Indexes API: issue with querying large files

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am working on a tool that would allow the user query the properties of Revit model elements stored on Autodesk BIM360. I am using Forge indexes API and implement a workflow similar to the one documented [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/model-properties/query/).

It works great for small models, however it starts crashing on large ones. Querying the entire property index with [Get Index Properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-properties-get/) results in error code 0, while applying any query to the index ([Post Queries](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-query-post/)) returns a query in `state = FAILED`, with the error as follows:

```
type: "RuntimeError"
title: "AmazonS3Exception"
detail: "The character number in one record is more than our max threshold, maxCharsPerRecord: 1,048,576"
```

This seems to be related to the issue explained in [this blog post](https://twydev.github.io/aws/aws-s3-select/), namely querying the entire json collection as a single object by calling `from S3Object[*]` as stated in [Model Property Service Query Language Reference](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/model-properties/query-ref/). Is there a way to fix it on the API caller end or is it a bug on the side of Forge? Help will be more than welcome. Thanks!

Comment: it sounds you specify query when building the index. Could you share the payload of request of the call? I guess it may be something special with your query .. In addition, did you run the same payload with both small and big model?

Comment: Thanks @Xiaodong-Liang for the response. I did quite a bit of testing with the following outcomes:
 - small files work fine for both extracting the entire index without query applied as well as with a query
 - large files do not work neither for extracting the entire index without query (response with error code 0) nor with any query (regardless of whether it accepts all elements or filters particular one by Id), in the latter case the error being as above (state == FAILED) 

So I am pretty sure the issue is related to the size of the model.

Comment: thank you for the investigation. Could you send us the index id (+ query id if separate calls) of the failure job ?we will check the backend log.